# Is there anyway to turn of jellybean touch responsiveness

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there anyway to turn off jellybean touch responsiveness. Its causing FPS lag for my games. The games a FPS Shooter so its necessary for it to not lag up. I know its touch responsiveness because when I actively drag my finger on the screen the FPS goes to Max but drops again if i let go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in whatever view u r using put make it clicable false

`android:clickable="false"`

put this line and check result